# Mobile Hotspot not found

Tags: wifi, tethering

why does my macbook wifi not recognize my att mobile hot spot on first try?  Sometimes I need to turn wifi on and off several times before if finds the hotspot when scanning for it.

Comment: move it up in your wifi list